# c# create object for .show() and .hide()

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, class, object

Is there a way to create a method that goes like this in C#:

```
public void showHide(string shOne, string shTwo, string shThree) {
     button1.shOne();
     button2.shTwo();
     button3.shThree();
}

private void discountButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    showHide("Show", "Hide", "Hide")
    // I was thinking that this should be the same as
    // button1.Show();
    // button2.Hide();
    // button3.Hide();
}
```

Is this possible ? I'm designing a c# application for thesis and I need to show and hide buttons (lots of buttons and labels and stuff).

I'm using this code as of now but I keep getting error:

> Panel' does not contain a definition for 'shOne'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public void showHide(bool shOne, bool shTwo, bool shThree) 
{
     button1.Visible = shOne;
     button2.Visible = shTwo;
     button3.Visible = shThree;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by multiple ways here is my code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (button2.Visible == false)
        {
            button2.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            button2.Hide();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yep. Thanks a lot too. This codes will surely help.